# fastify-request-context is not working for POST API calls

Tags: fastify

This is my fastify server written in typescript while using the fastify-request-context plugin  I am able to access the context of fastify request when I am requesting the resource using the GET method,
But I am not able to access the context of fastify request if I am requesting the resource using POST method

````
import fastify from 'fastify';
const { fastifyRequestContextPlugin } = require('fastify-request-context');
const server = fastify({
    logger: true
});
const preValidationFn = (req, reply, done): any => {
    req.requestContext.set('hello', 'hello world');
    console.log(req.requestContext.get('hello'));
    done();
};
const handlerFn = (req, reply): any => {
    console.log(req.requestContext.get('hello'));
    reply.send('hello world');
};
server.route({
    url: '/test',
    method: ['GET', 'POST'],
    preValidation: preValidationFn,
    handler: handlerFn
});

server.register(fastifyRequestContextPlugin);
console.log('Starting fastify Typescript server ');
server.listen(8085, '0.0.0.0', (err, address): void => {
    if (err) {
        console.warn(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.info(`Server listening at ${address}`);
});


process.on('uncaughtException', error => {
    console.error(error);
});
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
    console.error(error);
});```
````

Comment: what versions are you using? I tried your code and it works for me. did you rebuild the server?

Comment: I am using fastify version 3.x
Yes I did rebuild the server

Comment: https://github.com/rahul2123/fastify-server/tree/master
here is the git repository where you can try to replicate the issue
@ManuelSpigolon

Comment: Download and installed, it works: `curl -X POST http://localhost:8085/test                                                                            hello world` Could you add a curl to replicate?

Comment: What node version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Node 12

Comment: ```curl -X POST http://localhost:8085/test -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"abc","password":"abc"}'
```


Try this an req.context will log undefined, It's when I am sending data using POST method it is not logging anything to console,

If I try a POST request with no data I can access the request context